# Entity Framework Core: one-to-one relationship

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to do a one-to-one relationship without success.

The data model is in the image below. One user has one role:

[image]

Here is the code that I've used. First the models for UserRole and User entities and then the mappings.

Model UserRole:

```
public class UserRole 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddedWhen { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedWhen { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Model User:

```
public class User 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddedWhen { get; set; }
    public DateTime? UpdatedWhen { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
    public long UserRoleId { get; set; }
}
```

The mappings for UserRole:

```
public class UserRoleMap
{
    public UserRoleMap(EntityTypeBuilder<UserRole> entityBuilder)
    {
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Name).IsRequired();
        entityBuilder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasDefaultValueSql("1");
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.UpdatedWhen).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
        entityBuilder.Property(t => t.AddedWhen).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
    }
}
```

The mappings for User:

```
  public class UserMap
  {   
        public UserMap(EntityTypeBuilder<User> entityBuilder)
        {

            entityBuilder.HasKey(t => t.Id);
            entityBuilder.Property(t => t.IsActive).HasDefaultValueSql("1");
            entityBuilder.Property(t => t.UpdatedWhen).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
            entityBuilder.Property(t => t.AddedWhen).HasDefaultValueSql("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP");
            entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Email).IsRequired();
            entityBuilder.Property(t => t.Password).IsRequired();
            entityBuilder.Property(t => t.UserName).IsRequired();

            entityBuilder.
                HasOne<UserRole>(s => s.UserRole)
                .WithMany(g => g.Users)
                .HasForeignKey(s => s.UserRoleId);
        }
    }
```

The "general" mappings class:

```
 public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
 {
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            _ = new UserMap(modelBuilder.Entity<User>());
            _ = new UserRoleMap(modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>());
        }
    }
```

I've been trying other solutions that I found, but none of them worked.
When I get a user I wish to see its role. But the property UserRole is always null.

Comment: It's a 1:n relationship. And you forgot to explain the problem.

Comment: Sorry!
When I get a user I wish to see its role. But the property UserRole (from User model) is always null.

Comment: As a linked table in EF, have you asked the database for it when you load your User object? see: [EF Core Table Queries](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/querying-in-ef-core.aspx) (Specifically the "Include" syntax)

Comment: @Jcbo can you share your fetching code. you must be missing the navigation property loading mechanism. You can eager load UserRole when querying User like _context.Users.Include(u=> u.UserRole).FirstOrDefault(u=> u.Id == Id)